# Testing the statistical significance of regression coefficients in a logistic regression

Tags: logistic, statistical-significance, regression-coefficients, z-statistic

Are only the p-values relevant when testing the regression coefficients of a logistic regression? Does the z-value of a coefficient give any further information about the significance of the coefficient?

I know how the z-values are to be estimated, but I have some difficulties with interpreting it for each coefficient, so I am not sure if it gives any information about its significance.

Comment: The $z$-value is directly linked to the $p$-value. The two-sided $p$-value for each regression coefficient is calculated as $2\cdot \Phi(-|z|)$ where $\Phi$ denotes the CDF of the standard normal distribution.

Comment: COOLSerdash's comment covers the central issue; I'd only add that the two tailed $p$-value is monotonic in $|z|$ and so the only additional information you can get from $z$ that you can't see in $p$ would be its sign (which doesn't relate to significance in the two-tailed case).

Answer (score 1):

In a logistic regression, are you sure you aren't using chi-square values instead of z-values?  I've always seen Wald (if asymptotics are appropriate) and likelihood ratio chi-square values used to measure statistical significance in logistic regression.

Either way, the p-value corresponding to a chi-square value for a logistic regression coefficient has the same interpretation as the p-value corresponding to an F-value for a linear regression coefficient.

In logistic regression, the p-value corresponding to the calculated chi-square value is the probability of seeing a chi-square value at least as high as the calculated chi-square value for the equivalent model without that coefficient.

Comment: You can get z-values as asymptotically normal test statistics ($\hat\beta/\hat{\sigma}_\beta$) for individual coefficients.

Comment: @Glen_b You're right, sorry. I was thinking of the Wald chi-square statistic instead of the Wald normal statistic.